# Can't add a Project Reference in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net, clipboard

I'm on a new PC and I wanted to do a Coding Project. I wanted to code a Console App that uses your Clipboard.
I searched on how to do that and got the answer that I should use System.Windows.Forms. But if I want to add a Project Reference, it doesn't show up the tab "Assemblies". I installed every version of .net core and framework. I just can't add a project reference. In the installation of VS I had not much Drive Space left, so I only checked the option .NET desktop development.

Comment: Creating a Windows Form application is too complicated to guess your way through. You need to find a book or online tutorial.

Comment: your question is unclear. In this case you want a Windows specific assembly reference. You need to make sure that your consoleApp is created under .NET framework and not .NET core because .NET core is cross-platform

Comment: @snus74 thank you, that was the problem

Comment: @af2111 good to know it solved your problem, could you EDIT your question or add an answer with the solution and close the topic please?

Answer (score -1):

You have to Browse and include the file **System.Windows.Forms.dll** manually.
In my case, that file is in the following folder:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.7.2

[image: Reference Manager]